# SCCM OSD "no task sequences available for this computer"

Tags: sccm

I keep running into the scenario were SCCM OSD has failed to find any task sequences advertised for the current computer and I need to delete a computer accocation and re-add it. When I re-add the computer thru computer association the computer never shown in the collection I have created for the OSD advertisement. It seems like the mac address is still referenced some where in SCCM so I can't re-add it.

How do I track down where the MAC address is listed and clean out the references so I can re-add it to SCCM.

Thanks,
Dean Miller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the built-in default SCCM reports you should be able to find a report called "MAC - Computers for a specific MAC address" (under the Network category). Just put your MAC address in there (colon separate the character pairs in the MAC) and search, it should back with any SCCM known machines with that MAC that you can then look for in the main console and delete.

Alternatively (and slightly more work), create a new collection, create a query membership rule with a criteria something like "Network Adapter" - "MAC Address" and put your MAC in as the value. It should now list any known machines with that MAC.